# Register Service Provider via Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

In my app, I have registered service providers base on middleware. Here is the sample code

```
class DomesticFlightMiddleware{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->register('aunicaj\Providers\DomesticTravelServiceProvider');
    }

}
```

on another middleware

```
class InternationalFlightMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->register('aunicaj\Providers\InternationalTravelServiceProvider');

    }
}
```

This is working fine but when I execute php artisan route:list I get the following error

Target (Interface) is not Instantiable while building (Controller).

Are there any other way to conditionally register service providers?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when registering service provider in route middleware?

Comment: Hello, I have multiple transaction types (domestic ticketing, international ticketing). Both of this use the same contract, but of different implementations. when the user needs to book a domestic ticket I will load the DomesticServiceProvider via Middleware and same with other Transactions

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Did you try using deferred provider? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#deferred-providers

Comment: I did, I should mention this is working using client browser, but not when I type php artisan route:list. I think middlewares are not process when executing route:list

Comment: Indeed they are not processed. I think you should add your provider to `config/app.php`, and if it's deferred provider, then it won't be loaded immediately anyway (only when it's required).